# How to access all users in a Google Apps for business domain?

Tags: api, google-apps

I have a google apps for business account and I have registered 30 mails in my hosted domain (aswajith.com), like ask@aswajith.

Now I want to access all that user email accounts in web application through api. How to retrieve all users in that domain?

Comment: Take a look over the Directory API. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/

Answer (score 0):

Horrey i got it .

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users

This is api link for the above query.